# adding a percentage column to a dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm sorry I'm very new to python.
I have a dataset "olympics games":
dataset and columns

```
olympics.isnull().sum
ID             0
Name           0
Sex            0
Age         9315
Height     58814
Weight     61527
Team           0
NOC            0
Games          0
Year           0
Season         0
City           0
Sport          0
Event          0
Medal     229959
dtype: int64
```

and I have created a dataframe that shows the number of athletics grouped by 'Sex' for the USA team

```
sex_counts_usa = pd.DataFrame(team_usa.groupby('Sex').count()['ID']).sort_values(by = 'Sex', ascending = False)
```

how can I add to this dataframe a new column to show the same results but as percentages?

many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```py
# count athletes by sex
sex_counts_usa = team_usa['Sex'].value_counts().to_frame('Count')
# percentage of athletes by sex
sex_counts_usa['Percentage'] = (sex_counts_usa / sex_counts_usa.sum() * 100).astype('string') + '%'
```

If the aim is only to count by some column such as Sex, it's better to use `.value_counts()` rather than `.groupby('Sex').count()['ID']` in my opinion.

`value_counts()` can be called twice, once for the counts and again (with `normalize=True` parameter) for the percentages.

```py
result = pd.DataFrame({
    'Count': team_usa['Sex'].value_counts(), 
    'Percentage': team_usa['Sex'].value_counts(normalize=True)
})
```